# Склеивание элементов списка каждого с каждым

Tags: python, list

Есть список.

```
spis = ['qwert', '123', '321']
```

Мне нужно склеить каждый элемент списка с каждым элементом.
Т.е в данном случае должно получиться так :

```
qwert;123
qwert;321
123;qwert
123;321
321;qwert
321;123
```

Answer (score 5):

Воспользуйтесь [itertools.permutations](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations):

```
from itertools import permutations

result = ' '.join([';'.join(t) for t in permutations(spis, 2)])

print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
qwert;123 qwert;321 123;qwert 123;321 321;qwert 321;123
```

Если результатом должен быть список:

```
result = [';'.join(t) for t in permutations(spis, 2)]

print(result)
```

Вывод:

```
['qwert;123', 'qwert;321', '123;qwert', '123;321', '321;qwert', '321;123']
```

Comment: Ещё вариант: `print(*map(';'.join, permutations(spis, 2)))` или `print(*[x+';'+y for x in spis for y in spis if x is not y])`

Comment: @jfs, да, изящно у вас получилось!